# CSS keyframes animation doesn't run in some browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm building a website and I've added a CSS keyframes animation, called by a link click (connected to a javascript function).

This is my CSS file:

```
#banner {
background-color: #00BBD2;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
animation-duration: 1s;
animation-name: resizeBanner;
animation-fill-mode: forwards;
animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes resizeBanner {
from {height: 100%; background-color: #00BBD2}
to {height: 30%; background-color: #009688;}
}
```

And I'm starting the animation inside a javascript function like so:

```
<script>
    function animate()
    {
        document.getElementById('banner').style.webkitAnimationPlayState = "running";
    }
</script>
```

The animation runs perfectly in some browsers, while in others - it doesn't run at all. **How can this be?**

The Jquery animation that I run after the keyframes animation, however, always runs. Called like this:

```
$("#someid").fadeOut();
```

Comment: you use `webkitAnimationPlayState` - it works only in weblit browsers like CH, Opera, Safary, but would not work in FF, IE etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check it:

```
function animate() {
    // Code for Chrome, Safari, and Opera
    document.getElementById("banner").style.WebkitAnimationPlayState = "running";

    // Standard syntax
    document.getElementById("banner").style.animationPlayState = "running";
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer asap I can. Why are there two possibilities? Are there any pro's and con's?

Comment: 2 possibilities - because it is too many browsers now, and not a lot of standarts and rools in this part on specifications... Pros and cons... hm.. i think 2 calls is bad for performanse, but for you it's the only workaround of this issue, now. Maybe in future Webkit will implement `animationPlayState` in their browsers, and we will have only 1 call :)

Comment: Hmm, but I can use the standard syntax alone? With only 1 call - for all browsers?

Comment: no, now `animationPlayState` property will not work in some webkit browsers, but in future i hope we can :)

Comment: So you'd have to either call both of them, or check what browser the user is currently using?

Comment: use 2 of tham. Checking browser - is another operation, that reduse performanse. Browser will get the property, that it can understand.